# Конвертация pd.Series в pd.Dataframe определенного формата

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Существует одномерный массив **b**

```
b = pd.Series(
[110.0, 120.0, Horsepower]
[150.0, 175.0, Horsepower]
[1351.0, 1601.0, Capacity]
[12.0, 14.0, Metric Tons]
[1601.0, 1751.0, Capacity])
Name: fiProductClassDesc, dtype: object
```

- Первая цифра списка - минимальное значение
- Вторая цифра списка - максимальное значение
- Третье значение - название категории (всего 4 шт.)

Необходимо создать из него `a = pd.Dataframe`, всего 8 колонок, где для каждой строки, значения будут присвоены только тем колонкам, для которых совпадает название категории и лэйбла колонки. Остальные 0.

```
Digging Depth_min   Digging Depth_max   Metric Tons_min Metric Tons_max Horsepower_min  Horsepower_max  Capacity_min    Capacity_max
0   0   0   0   110 120 0   0
0   0   0   0   150 175 0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1351    1601
0   0   12  14  0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1601    1751
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы делал это так:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(b.to_list()).rename(columns={0: "min", 1: "max"})
res = x.pivot_table(index=x.index, columns=2, fill_value=0).swaplevel(axis=1)
res.columns = res.columns.map("_".join)
res = res.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
```

---

результат:

```
In [115]: res
Out[115]:
   Metric Tons_min  Metric Tons_max  Horsepower_min  Horsepower_max  Capacity_min  Capacity_max
0                0                0             110             120             0             0
1                0                0             150             175             0             0
2                0                0               0               0          1351          1601
3               12               14               0               0             0             0
4                0                0               0               0          1601          1751
```

PS думаю добавить нулевые столбцы `Digging Depth_min` и `Digging Depth_max` проблем не составит

---

пошаговое решение:

```
In [116]: pd.DataFrame(b.to_list()).rename(columns={0: "min", 1: "max"})
Out[116]:
      min     max            2
0   110.0   120.0   Horsepower
1   150.0   175.0   Horsepower
2  1351.0  1601.0     Capacity
3    12.0    14.0  Metric Tons
4  1601.0  1751.0     Capacity

In [117]: x.pivot_table(index=x.index, columns=2, fill_value=0).swaplevel(axis=1)
Out[117]:
2 Capacity Horsepower Metric Tons Capacity Horsepower Metric Tons
       max        max         max      min        min         min
0        0        120           0        0        110           0
1        0        175           0        0        150           0
2     1601          0           0     1351          0           0
3        0          0          14        0          0          12
4     1751          0           0     1601          0           0

In [120]: res
Out[120]:
   Capacity_max  Horsepower_max  Metric Tons_max  Capacity_min  Horsepower_min  Metric Tons_min
0             0             120                0             0             110                0
1             0             175                0             0             150                0
2          1601               0                0          1351               0                0
3             0               0               14             0               0               12
4          1751               0                0          1601               0                0

In [121]: res.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
Out[121]:
   Metric Tons_min  Metric Tons_max  Horsepower_min  Horsepower_max  Capacity_min  Capacity_max
0                0                0             110             120             0             0
1                0                0             150             175             0             0
2                0                0               0               0          1351          1601
3               12               14               0               0             0             0
4                0                0               0               0          1601          1751
```

Comment: Действительно, метод pivot_table оказался очень полезным для решения моей проблемы. Спасибо!